# Count number of lines a program outputs in 1 second

Tags: unix

I'm trying to count the number of filesystem disk calls that occur in one second on my computer using `fs_usage`. Ideally I'd like to pipe `fs_usage` into something like `head`, except that will take 1 second worth of output from the function rather than a given number of lines. Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

```
#!/bin/bash
# run fs_usage, piping the output into the output file
fs_usage > output &
pid=$! # get the pid of fs_usage
# sleep for 1 second
sleep 1s
kill $pid # kill fs_usage
wc -l output
rm output # optional, but I like to clean up after myself
```

No guarantees it'll work right off the bat, I'm not on a *nix box at the moment.

The idea is that you fork fs_usage to the background and then wait for a bit in the script before killing it.

Comment: `cat output` should probably be `wc -l output` or similar. And the sleep call takes a single argument (i.e., `1s` with no whitespace in between). I fixed it for you.

Comment: Right, I missed that he just wanted the number of operations.

Comment: I was hoping for something that wouldn't process the data as a stream without depending on writing the results to disk, so that it could handle an extremely rapid flow of data. I guess I'd have to write a program for that, I think this will work in smaller cases though. Thanks.

Comment: For that, you probably ought to write a simple perl script.